# How to wrap every third table cell with a row within Kentico for email template?

Tags: javascript, kentico, email-templates

How can I wrap every 3rd `<td>` with a `<tr>` using Kentico email template?

I wrote the following code in jQuery, but do not have knowledge or idea how to write this loop logic in Kentico.

```js
var td = $("#myTable tr td");           // Getting all td
td.each(function(i) {                   // Looping the td
  if (i % 3 == 0) {                     // Splitting td as multiple of 3
    td.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll('<tr/>') // Wrapping it inside tr
  }
}).parent('tr').unwrap();
```

I want the same logic using Kentico.

Comment: Do you want to use jQuery code in your email body? It's not a good practice to have Javascript in your emails. Please refer to Sending html email having JQuery scripts or Is JavaScript supported in an email message? questions.

Or could you please clarify your question? As it doesn't make sense what do you have and what do you want to achieve.

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery. I just added that I want the same jQuery logic in Kentico Syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to replace the JS with Kentico Macro which can be used in email template or email widget?

If so, and you have Kentico 11+, then you can go to Email marketing application > Email widgets and open the "Latest Article" sample widget and look at how the logic works.

Here is the HTML/macro for the sample widget

```
{% /*
The Latest articles email widget dynamically obtains four latest articles from the Dancing Goat demo site at the time when the email issue is generated.
It achieves so by using macros that access pages with the given attributes.
*/ @%}

{% 
  articles = Documents["/Articles"]
               .CultureVersions["en-US"]
               .Children
                 .ClassNames("dancinggoat.article")
                 .OrderBy("DocumentPublishFrom DESC")
                 .TopN(4)
                 .WithAllData; 
return; 
#%}

<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="500">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="top" width="500">
<![endif]-->
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:500px;">

{%
  i = 0;
  isFirstItemInRow = false;
  foreach (article in articles) { 
%}

{% 
    isFirstItemInRow = (Modulo(i, 2) == 0);
    articleUrl = UTMContent == String.Empty ? article.RelativeURL : article.RelativeURL + "?utm_content=" + UTMContent;
    articleTeaserUrl = GetAttachmentUrlByGUID(article.ArticleTeaser, "teaser", "teaser");
    articleLinkText = LinkText == String.Empty ? "Continue reading" : LinkText;
    return; 
%}

{%  if (isFirstItemInRow)  { %}
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:0; padding: 10px 0 15px 0" class="padding">
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="500">
<tr>
<![endif]-->
{% } /* END if */ #%}

<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<td align="left" valign="top" width="240">
<![endif]-->
      <div style="display:inline-block; margin: 0 -2px; max-width:50%; min-width:240px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;" class="wrapper">
        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="{% isFirstItemInRow ? "max-width:240px;" : "max-width:240px; float:right;" %}" class="wrapper">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 20px 0 30px 0;">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="middle"><a href="{% articleUrl #%}" target="_blank"><img src="{% articleTeaserUrl #%}" width="240" height="130" style="display: block; color: #666666; font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; width: 240px; height: 130px;" alt="Fluid images" border="0" class="img-max"></a></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="padding: 15px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; font-size: 20px;">{% article.ArticleTitle #%}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="padding: 5px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;">{% article.ArticleSummary #%}</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="padding: 5px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px;"><a href="{% articleUrl #%}" target="_blank" style="color: #256F9C; text-decoration: none;">{% articleLinkText #%} &rarr;</a></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
</td>
<![endif]-->

{%  if (isFirstItemInRow)  { %}
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<td width="20" style="font-size: 1px;">&nbsp;</td>
<![endif]-->
{% } /* END if */ #%}      


{%  if (!isFirstItemInRow)  { %}
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
</tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->                                    
</td>
</tr>
{% } /* END if */ #%} 

{% i++; return; %} 
{% } /* END foreach */ #%} 

</table>
```

Comment: Bundle of thanks Rui, could you please share the exact url of the Sample widget?
as I can't find that

Comment: There is no URL to it, it's virtually in the Email Marketing application > Email widgets. If you don't have the sample site, I'll paste the code below.